# Dealing with nginx 400 "The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port" error

Tags: nginx

I'm running a Sinatra app behind passenger/nginx. I'm trying to get it to respond to both http and https calls. The problem is, when both are defined in the server block https calls are responded to normally but http yields a 400 "The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port" error. This is for a static page so I'm guessing Sinatra has nothing to do with this. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Here's the server block:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443  ssl;
        server_name localhost;
        root /home/myhome/app/public;
        passenger_enabled on;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate      /opt/nginx/ssl_keys/ssl.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  /opt/nginx/ssl_keys/ssl.key;
        ssl_protocols        SSLv3 TLSv1;
        ssl_ciphers          HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

        location /static {
            root  /home/myhome/app/public;
            index  index.html index.htm index.php;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        error_page 500 /500.html;

        access_log /home/myhome/app/logs/access.log;
        error_log /home/myhome/app/logs/error.log;
}
```

Comment: In my case was that the url in browser: `my.example.com:443` didn't work. Changing that instead to `https://my.example.com` worked. Weird, never had this problem with apache.

Comment: `ssl on;` tells NGINX to server **ANY** content through SSL. Use "ssl" flag at the end of your `listen 443;` e.g `listen 443 ssl;`if your server delivers both http and https traffic, and remove `ssl on;` directive.

Answer (score 209, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem.  It works on one server and does not on another server with same Nginx configuration.  Found the the solution which is answered by Igor here http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,1612,1627#msg-1627

Yes. Or you may combine SSL/non-SSL servers in one server:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443 default ssl;

  # ssl on   - remember to comment this out

}
```

Comment: Per what rapam iosif says, be sure you also include `ssl off;`

Comment: You only need to remove the line `ssl on;` (no need to add ssl off). Also, since I don't remember which Nginx version, there is no more need to use `default` on `listen 443` line. So the OP config was OK, only need to remove `ssl on` and it should work.

Comment: @bobojam feel free to include the explanation from my answer, so that yours will be more complete. I've asked OP author to accept you answer.

Comment: How does it solve the SSL purpose by commenting `ssl on`. @MichaelJ.Evans answer below is a much better solution.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with multiple conf files. Says there are 2 duplicate defaults. Use Alexander's solution.

Comment: as noted below by Michael J. Evans   `error_page 497 https://$server_name:$server_port$request_uri;` should be used

Comment: Confirming (what worked for me): `ssl on;` needs to be removed, and `listen 443 default ssl;` needs to actually be `listen 443 ssl;`.

Comment: Thanks, In my case **Uncommented global** `ssl on` was the problem

Answer (score 62):

The above answers are incorrect in that most over-ride the 'is this connection HTTPS' test to allow serving the pages over http irrespective of connection security.

The secure answer using an error-page on an NGINX specific http 4xx error code to redirect the client to retry the same request to https. (as outlined here https://serverfault.com/questions/338700/redirect-http-mydomain-com12345-to-https-mydomain-com12345-in-nginx )

The OP should use:

```
server {
  listen        12345;
  server_name   php.myadmin.com;

  root         /var/www/php;

  ssl           on;

  # If they come here using HTTP, bounce them to the correct scheme
  error_page 497 https://$server_name:$server_port$request_uri;

  [....]
}
```

Comment: You probably want $server_name instead of $host, the server_name presumably being set to the CN that the SSL cert authenticates. That way, the user won't get a scare screen if they came in via an IP or localhost.

Comment: I was trying to implement this on my local install of [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/), but used the [Inserting custom NGINX settings into the GitLab server block](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/settings/nginx.md#inserting-custom-nginx-settings-into-the-gitlab-server-block) method thus `nginx['custom_gitlab_server_config'] = "error_page 497 https://$host:$server_port$request_uri;"` did the trick

Comment: While `$server_name` prevents users from Scare Screening, sometimes you still want to use `$host` instead. In my case `docker run` sends a request that ends up in `$server_name` being empty, but `$host` being set as expected.

Answer (score 19):

The error says it all actually. Your configuration tells Nginx to listen on port 80 (HTTP) and use SSL. When you point your browser to `http://localhost`, it tries to connect via HTTP. Since Nginx expects SSL, it complains with the error.

The workaround is very simple. You need two `server` sections:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  // other directives...
}

server {
  listen 443;

  ssl on;
  // SSL directives...

  // other directives...
}
```

Comment: You don't actually need two server sections. Remove the "ssl on" line and change the listen lines as per @bobojam's answer.

Answer (score 16):

According to [wikipedia article on status codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error). Nginx has a custom error code when http traffic is sent to https port(error code 497)

And according to [nginx docs on error_page](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page), you can define a URI that will be shown for a specific error.
Thus we can create a uri that clients will be sent to when error code 497 is raised.

## nginx.conf

```
#lets assume your IP address is 89.89.89.89 and also 
#that you want nginx to listen on port 7000 and your app is running on port 3000

server {
    listen 7000 ssl;
 
    ssl_certificate /path/to/ssl_certificate.cer;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/ssl_certificate_key.key;
    ssl_client_certificate /path/to/ssl_client_certificate.cer;

    error_page 497 301 =307 https://89.89.89.89:7000$request_uri;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://89.89.89.89:3000/;

        proxy_pass_header Server;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;
    }
}
```

However if a client makes a request via any other method except a GET, that request will be turned into a GET. Thus to preserve the request method that the client came in via; we use error processing redirects as shown in [nginx docs on error_page](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page)

And thats why we use the `301 =307` redirect.

Using the nginx.conf file shown here, we are able to have http and https listen in on the same port

Comment: this works for me - error_page 497 301 =307 https://89.89.89.89:7000$request_uri;

Comment: this worked , just keep remove `ssl on `

Answer (score 12):

I had the exact same issue, I have kind of the same configuration as your exemple and I got it working by removing the line :

`ssl on;`

To quote the doc:

> If HTTP and HTTPS servers are equal, a single server that handles both HTTP and HTTPS requests may be configured by deleting the directive “ssl on” and adding the ssl parameter for *:443 port

Comment: Any chance you have the link to doc?

Answer (score 9):

Here is an example to config **HTTP** and **HTTPS** in same config block with **ipv6** support. The config is tested in **Ubuntu Server** and **NGINX/1.4.6** but this should work with all servers.

```
server {
    # support http and ipv6
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    # support https and ipv6
    listen 443 default_server ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ipv6only=on default_server ssl;

    # path to web directory
    root /path/to/example.com;
    index index.html index.htm;

    # domain or subdomain
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    # ssl certificate
    ssl_certificate /path/to/certs/example_com-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/certs/example_com.key;

    ssl_session_timeout 5m;

    ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers "HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5 or HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES";
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
}
```

Don't include `ssl on` which may cause `400` error. The config above should work for

> http://example.com
>
> http://www.example.com
>
> https://example.com
>
> https://www.example.com

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

Actually you can do this with:

```
ssl off;
```

This solved my problem in using nginxvhosts; now I am able to use both SSL and plain HTTP. 
Works even with combined ports.

Comment: Works for me on nginx/1.6.3 :)

Answer (score 4):

if use phpmyadmin add: fastcgi_param HTTPS on;

Answer (score 2):

its error 497 and not error 400 . you can handle Error 497 like this and redirect http to https with a 301 (moved permanently) or 302 (moved temporary) like this:

```
error_page 497 = @foobar;

location @foobar {
return 301 https://$host:$server_port$request_uri;
}
```

this will redirect you to the exact url you requested but replace your request 'http' with 'https' with no error or confirm (its 301 redirect and counts as seo safe)

Answer (score 0):

In my case my response redirected from jenkins to 443

Just added a proxy redirect in nginx configuration to make it work

`proxy_redirect http://test.example.com:443/ https://test.example.com/`;

Answer (score 0):

In my case just those lines help me:

```
   if ($scheme = 'http') {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.