# artifactory pro registry docker image

Tags: ssl, nginx, docker, artifactory

I am trying out the 30 day trial version of the artifactory-registry docker image to evaluate the docker repository for our internal use. I am following the documentation https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Running+with+Docker

After I run the docker image I am able to access the UI on port 8081, however When I try to push an image I get the following error 
“The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port”

Heres how I deploy the image

sudo docker pull mysql
sudo docker tag mysql localhost:5002/mysql
sudo docker push localhost:5002/mysql

Also the documentation says that artifactory could be accessed on the following URLS

http://localhost/artifactory
http://localhost:8081/artifactory
https://localhost:5000/v2 (This is mapped to http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/docker/docker-remote/v2)
https://localhost:5001/v1 (This is mapped to http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/docker/docker-prod-local/v1)
https://localhost:5002/v1 (This is mapped to http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/docker/docker-dev-local/v1)
https://localhost:5001/v2 (This is mapped to http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/docker/docker-prod-local/v2)
https://localhost:5002/v2 (This is mapped to http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/docker/docker-dev-local/v2)

But I get a 404 trying to access any of the https urls

What am I missing?

Comment: I've seen that you had many issues before with configuring Artifactory as a Docker registry. I suggest contacting JFrog support at support@jfrog.com. You can approach them as part of your trial process and they would love to help

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an NGINX configuration issue (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768946/dealing-with-nginx-400-the-plain-http-request-was-sent-to-https-port-error) ) with not forwarding HTTPS requests to Artifactory.

Changing the configuration to forward your requests should fix your issue.