# Nginx 400 “The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port” error with SSL on Node JS application

Tags: node.js, ssl, nginx

I have two NodeJS application running on port 3000 and 3001 behind NGINX, So I have done a proxy over NGINX through port 80 to NodeJS Application running on 3000 and 3001 port. It is running with no issue and I am able to access the application from public network by DNS on port 80 but When I have configured the SSL on NGINX port 443 It gives error **`The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port with 400 status`** while port 80 is still accessible with no issue.

**NGINX CONFIGURATION**

```
user nginx;  
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
   worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
   log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
   access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

   sendfile            on;
   tcp_nopush          on;
   tcp_nodelay         on;
   keepalive_timeout   65;
   types_hash_max_size 2048;

   include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
   default_type        application/octet-stream;

   include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

   gzip  on;
   upstream app_nodejs {
      server 127.0.0.1:3000;
   }
   upstream api_nodejs {
      server 127.0.0.1:3001;
   }
   server {
       listen       80;
       listen       443 ssl;

       ssl_certificate      /home/foo/htdocs/SSLs/foo.crt;
       ssl_certificate_key  /home/foo/htdocs/SSLs/foo.key;
       ssl_protocols        SSLv3 TLSv1;
       ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

       location / {
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
          proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
          proxy_pass http://app_nodejs;
          proxy_redirect off;
       }
       location /api/ {
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
          proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
          proxy_pass http://api_nodejs;
          proxy_redirect off;
       }
   }
}
```

**Curl Response for Port 443 (`curl 127.0.0.1:443`)**

```
<html>
<head><title>400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</title></head>
  <body bgcolor="white">
    <center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
    <center>The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</center>
    <hr><center>nginx/1.6.3</center>
  </body>
</html>
```

for Browser It timeouts.

Comment: Use `curl https://...` and you don't need port number

Comment: duplicate ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768946/dealing-with-nginx-400-the-plain-http-request-was-sent-to-https-port-error

Comment: @AlexeyTen: I got this message 
`curl: (51) Unable to communicate securely with peer: requested domain name does not match the server's certificate.`

Comment: At least that means there is SSL. Use `-k` flag to ignore certificate mismatch.

Comment: @AlexeyTen: Using -k flag it gives me the proper output but how I will get it resolved for the browser request

Comment: You must use `https` and valid domain cert

Comment: @AlexeyTen : I have check SSL on third party tool it gives certificate is valid with proper chain but in browser i get blank response with REQUEST_TIMEOUT error in console