# Kubernetes ingress edit: HTTP 400 Bad request - The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

Could there be any reason why a webapp which perfectly loads up fine gives a `*HTTP 400 Bad request - The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS*` port after the webapp's ingress has been edited manually or edited through an automated job which updates the ingress modifying the Whitelisted IPs

Apparently, this issue gets fixed when we redeploy the webapp after *purging the webapp deployment*...

Any pointers to this would be great as this happens on our PROD env and not reproducible on any lower envs.
Points to note:-
- Nginx Ingress controller setup is the same across lower envs and Prod env.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 20M
    ingress.kubernetes.io/secure-backends: "true"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: xxx.yy.zz.pp/32, yyy.ss.dd.kkl/32
    ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range-status: unlocked
creationTimestamp: 2018-11-29T15:34:05Z
generation: 5
 labels:
   app: xyz-abc-pqr
  name: xxxx-webapp-yyyy-zzzz
  namespace: nspsace-name
  resourceVersion: "158237270"
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/nspsace-name/ingresses/xxxx-webapp-yyyy-zzzz
  uid: 348f892e-f3ec-11e8-aa6f-0a0340041348
  spec:
   rules:
    - host: ssssssss.wwwwweewwerwerw.co.uk
      http:
      paths:
       - backend:
          serviceName: xxxx-webapp-yyyy-zzzz
          servicePort: 443
        path: /
    - host: xxxx-webapp-yyyy-zzzz.bbbbv.lasdfkla.ajksdfh.ioohhsaf.pp
     http:
       paths:
        - backend:
          serviceName: xxxx-webapp-yyyy-zzzz
          servicePort: 443
       path: /
     tls:
       - hosts:
          - ssssssss.wwwwweewwerwerw.co.uk
          - xxxx-webapp-yyyy-zzzz.bbbbv.lasdfkla.ajksdfh.ioohhsaf.pp
         secretName: xxxx-webapp-yyyy-zzzz-server-tls
     status:
       loadBalancer:
        ingress:
         - {}
```

Comment: Can you post your Ingress YAML? And also describe _what_ exactly you change manually and _how_: `kubectl edit`?

Comment: yes using kubectl edit..Posted the ingress YAML above. We just change the Whitelisted IPs to restrict the webapp access the external world.

Comment: Make sure that your incremental deployments actually include an ingress update.  Maybe something like `helm upgrade --install (your-ingress)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be something wrong with the ingress controller and how it updates its configuration. I'm assuming you are using a [nginx ingress controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) so you can inspect the configs before an after:

```
$ kubectl cp <nginx-ingress-controller-pod>:nginx.conf nginx.conf.before
$ kubectl edit ingress <your-ingress>
$ kubectl cp <nginx-ingress-controller-pod>:nginx.conf nginx.conf.after
$ diff nginx.conf.before nginx.conf.after
```

You can see the this may happen with nginx because of something like this: [Dealing with nginx 400 "The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768946/dealing-with-nginx-400-the-plain-http-request-was-sent-to-https-port-error).

Comment: My web-application needs an internal ingress and an external ingress catering to internal traffic and to the outside world. The issue was not specifying/mentioning the **Ingress_Class** in the Internal ingress template which was creating additional ingress for handling external traffic which had incorrect host mappings different to the expected host URLs to be allowed externally. 

All the internal ingress controller Pods would have had the nginx.conf updated after specifying the right **INGRESS CLASS** annotation.

Comment: Hi @Avi could you please clarify a bit which of the ingress templates had the classname missing?

Comment: Hi @SteveK - the classname (annotation to point to the internal load balancer) was missing as part of internal ingress template.