# Use https applications with Jenkins X deployment

Tags: jenkins, https, kubernetes, .net-core, google-kubernetes-engine

I am evaluating Jenkins X to manage CI/CD on a Asp.NET application.

1. I created a new project with `[jx create quickstart aspnet-app][1]` all works perfekt with gke, application is visible over port 80.
2. I modified the app to works with dotnet core 2.2
3. application now listening on port 443 for https queries.

   - Works great when started with `docker run`.
   - when running from jenkins the pipeline do the job, container will be created and started on gke, but the application is not available on port 443.
   - I become `default backend - 404` instead of my page.

Question:
Where could I configure the opened ports. Any idea where I could investigate?

ps:
-  *When trying to contact port 443 over http I receive a `400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port` response from nginx, which is a pretty good sign.*
 - *Seem to be related with ingress, how can I configure ingress over Jenkins X*?

Thank you for any hint.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins X, as you can read in the [accessing applications section](https://jenkins.io/blog/2018/04/16/jenkins-x-explained-part1/), automatically installs a [Nginx ingress controller](http://elatov.github.io/2018/08/using-the-nginx-ingress-controller-with-kubernetes/) and seems that yours is configured for use SSL and non-SSL in same server. When you try to access through `http` Nginx expects SSL and gives you the error.

You can see in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768946/dealing-with-nginx-400-the-plain-http-request-was-sent-to-https-port-error) link a similar question in Stackoverflow, you must to modify the nginx.conf file and add a comment in the SSL line:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443 default ssl;

  # ssl on   <--- comment the line
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Did you know how JenkinsX invokes ingress? It difficult for me unterstand all dependencies and I can't find where ingress could be configured as you describe. It seems to me that Jenkins uses fabric8.io to archive that. Regards.

Comment: fabric8.io is the `expose` controller (https://github.com/jenkins-x/exposecontroller). It exposes the services for your Kubernetes cluster but the Nginx is the ingress controller (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#ingress-controllers) and I recommend you to check this configuration.