# nginx docker container on aws ecs >> The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port

Tags: docker, nginx, amazon-ecs, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a frontend angular application running on aws ecs ec2 instance and both are connected to TCP port 443 and 80 of network load balancer. I will have many vhost configured on this nginx docker container with multiple domain names. In the ecs service the container to load balance is given as port 443. We will have to choose either port 443 or 80 of the container to load balance. `https://prnt.sc/pocu41`.  On https the site is loading fine. But on http I am getting the error

```
The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port
```

I am planning to use the ssl certificate on the docker container and not the ssl on the load balancer. If I choose ssl on the load balancer then we need to use the multidomain ssl in application load balancer default certificate and may not feasible when there are hundreds of domain.

My Nginx conf looks like this

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name  example.com;

        root   /usr/share/nginx/html/docroot;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

        gzip on;
        gzip_min_length 1000;
        gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    }


server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com/example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com/example.com.key;

    server_name  example.com;
    root           /usr/share/nginx/html/docroot;
    index          index.html;
    location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

}
```

Any idea how we can solve this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

> I am planning to use the ssl certificate on the docker container and
>   not the ssl on the load balancer. If I choose ssl on the load balancer
>   then we need to use the multidomain ssl in application load balancer
>   default certificate and may not feasible when there are hundreds of
>   domain.

Your this assumption does not seem correct, you can create `*` certificate from LB  or you can configure [multiple from ACM as well](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=867822). you can use AWS ACM with load balancer and its totally **free of cost** and why I should bother to manage SSL at application level? and why I should open port 80 at application level when I can do redirect with application LB if NLB is not requirment?

**AWS Certificate Manager Pricing**

> Public SSL/TLS certificates provisioned through AWS Certificate
>   Manager are free. You pay only for the AWS resources you create to run
>   your application.

[certificate-manager-pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/pricing/)

Second any special reason for using **NLB**? For web-application I will never go for network balancer, NLB make sense for TCP level communication, But I will go for [application LB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-listeners.html) for HTTP communication which provides advance routings like **host base routing, redirect and path-based**  routing which will remove the need of Nginx.

Containers are designed for lightweight task and AWS recommends to memory arround 300-500MB and same recommendations for CPU.

**Do you know the cost of SSL termination at container level?**

SSL traffic can be **compute intensive** since it requires encryption and decryption of traffic. SSL relies on public key cryptography to encrypt communications between the client and server sending messages safely across networks.

**Advantage of SSL termination at LB level**

SSL termination at load balancer is desired because decryption is resource and CPU intensive. **Putting the decryption burden on the load balancer enables the server to spend processing power on application tasks**, which helps improve performance. It also simplifies the management of SSL certificates.

[new-tls-termination-for-network-load-balancers](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-tls-termination-for-network-load-balancers/)

[ssl-termination](https://avinetworks.com/glossary/ssl-termination/)

[image]

[10-tips-to-improve-the-performance-of-your-aws-application](https://www.slideshare.net/AmazonWebServices/aws-summit-tlv20140510-tips-to-improve-the-performance-of-your-aws-application)

So base on this I am not going to asnwer your problem as suggested by @Linpy may help if you still want to go, you can this too [dealing-with-nginx-400-the-plain-http-request-was-sent-to-https-port-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768946/dealing-with-nginx-400-the-plain-http-request-was-sent-to-https-port-error)

Comment: Yeh I understood that, I was using the application load balancer ssl certificate. But when we are having multiple domain names like domain1.com,domain2.com etc pointed to the same container, we can use the default rule to route that request but it will take the default ssl on the loadbalancer which may be single certificate of  a domain.  the load balancer also has a limit of 100 rules and 25 certificate too.  I think using a multidomain ssl certificate as the default ssl certificate can help here to some extent.

Comment: If you are reaching all these limit that are set by aws then it's mean there is problem in the application design, how you'll scale such applications that is strongly tight with nginx configuration? How you'll deal with DDOS? How you'll handle flood of request? Better to review application design and let put these thing load balancer